Delete files from destination if deleted from source using logic app
I am copying folders along with files from sharepoint to Azure Blob. I am using the below workflow-

I am doing a dailyload. the create blob action will copy all the folders and files.
Issue is when few files are deleted from sharepoint (source), it should be deleted in azure blob too. In current scenerio, using create action this is not possible. What should be the approach?
How can i delete complete files and folders from blob and do a create blob action?

You can use below design:

Then:

Now after deleting the file in sharepoint, the same file will be deleted in Blob storage.
Deleted file:

Output:
Whenever file deletes this will trigger and deletes the blob:



Hi @RithwikBojja Is there any way or action where i can delete all the folders and files and then use a create blob action. I want to use the same flow which i created to copy files(flow pasted in the question)

AFAIK, there isnt any direct way, one way i am able to think is get all files in blob and get all files from sharepoint and need to be compared.
